# What is the order of approximation required to calculate the arc length of a cubic spline using Gaussian quadrature?

Tags: numerical-methods, spline, numerical-calculus

I have a [cubic Hermite spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline) in three dimensions defined by
$$\mathbf{p}(t)=(2t^3-3t^2+1)\,\mathbf{p}_0+(t^3-2t^2+t)\,\mathbf{m}_0+(-2t^3+3t^2)\,\mathbf{p}_1+(t^3-t^2)\,\mathbf{m}_1,$$
where $\mathbf{p}_0$, $\mathbf{m}_0$, $\mathbf{p}_1$, and $\mathbf{m}_1$ are arbitrary vectors and $t \in [0, 1]$.

I'd like to numerically evaluate the total arc length over $t$, i.e.
$$\Delta s = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\mathbf{p}^\prime(t) \cdot \mathbf{p}^\prime(t)} \,\text{d}t.$$
I think it would be most efficient to use standard [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature), but I'm unsure what order of approximation to use. Since the integrand above is not a polynomial, I know I cannot choose an exact approximation, but can I in general limit the error to say $\leq\!1\%$?

Since the integrand is the square root of a fourth-order polynomial, I wonder if it can be satisfactorily approximated as a second-order polynomial. I can in principle evaluate the Taylor series of the integrand, but I don't know how to decide at what point the terms become negligibly small in general.

Comment: Your computation boils down to the integration of 

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{P(t)}dt$$

where $P$ is in general a fourth degree polynomial.

You have therefore a closed form formula in terms of elliptice functions.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2780313).

Comment: Thank you, it never occured to me to seek an analytical solution!